# Another definition of singular homology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homological-algebra, simplicial-complexes

The singular homology is defined via standard simplex. Now if I propose another definition of singular homology groups, based on arbitrary simplex, as follows:

Let $X$ be a topological space. A $n$-dimensional simplex $\Delta_n$ is the convex combination of a collection of affine independent vectors $(v_0, v_1, \cdots, v_n)$ in $R^m$ $(m \ge n)$, which means $(v_1-v_0, v_2-v_0, \cdots, v_n-v_0)$ are linear independent. A $n$-dimensional singular simplex is a continuous map from a $n$-dimensional simplex to $X$: $f:\Delta_n \rightarrow X$. The boundary map $\partial f$ is defined as the restriction of $f$ to its faces as usual. A singular simplex chain is an integer linear combination of singular simplexes. The resulting homology groups is defined normally, and denoted by $H_{m,*}(X, Z)$.

There is a natural homomorphism from $H_{m,*}(X, Z)$ to $H_{m+1,*}(X, Z)$ induced by the standard embedding from $R^m$ into $R^{m+1}$. Let $\hat{H}_*(X,Z):=\lim_{\rightarrow}H_{m,*}(X,Z)$

So my question is: is this new definition of singular homology groups $\hat{H}_*(X,Z)$ are canonically isomorphic to the standard singular homology?

The motivation is that in some cases of mine this definition is more convenient.

Comment: You have to say something about how simplices in $R^m$ for different $m$ relate (otherwise even in $H_0(\mathrm{pt})$, two different $0$-simplices in, say, $R^2$ and $R^3$ represent different classes).

Comment: Is $\Delta_n$ really supposed to be this collection of vectors, or the convex span of them?

Comment: Actually it is not just for different $m$, but even for same $m$, we need to know how different simplices relate.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this definition? Other than some technical issues being pointed out, it looks like you are trying to do the standard definition, but with the simplicies linearly-embedded in Euclidean space.

Comment: This definition is clearly equivalent to the one with the standard simplex and it is used in textbooks like Hatcher's. The only thing you need to keep track of, is the order of the spanning vectors $v_1,\dots,v_n$.

Comment: @Zero As noted by the other commenters, it is not clearly equivalent until you mod out by some relations among the various singular simplices. In particular, it is necessary to have something like $f:\Delta_a \to X$ is equivalent to $g:\Delta_b\to X$ if there is an order-preserving isomorphism $\phi:\Delta_a\to \Delta_b$ such that $g\phi=f$.

Comment: @Greg Friedman: of course, that's part of the definition, how you relate the standard simplex to an arbitrary simplex. I didn't know that that was a problem.

Comment: I have proved this, but no need any "equivalence" in the definition aprior.